# DevIL error 1290. How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, devil

I would like to load image to my application, but I have an error:
http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/5814/blad07864.png

This is a code of this application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#undef _UNICODE
#include "il.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "DevIL.lib" )

// Wow. DevIL is amazing.

// From http://gpwiki.org/index.php/DevIL:Tutorials:Basics

// The library consists of three sub-libraries:
//  * IL - main DevIL library. It allows you to load and save images to files. Every function in this library have 'il' prefixed to their name.
//  * ILU - this library contains functions for altering images. Every function in this library have 'ilu' prefixed to their name.
//  * ILUT - this library connects DevIL with OpenGL. Every function in this library have 'ilut' prefixed to their name.

int main()
{
  ilInit();
  printf("DevIL has been initialized\n");

  // Loading an image
  ILboolean result = ilLoadImage( "tex1.png" ) ;

  if( result == true )
  {
    printf("the image loaded successfully\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("The image failed to load\n" ) ;

    ILenum err = ilGetError() ;
    printf( "the error %d\n", err );
    printf( "string is %s\n", ilGetString( err ) );
  }

  int size = ilGetInteger( IL_IMAGE_SIZE_OF_DATA ) ;
  printf("Data size:  %d\n", size );
  ILubyte * bytes = ilGetData() ;

  for( int i = 0 ; i < size; i++ )
  {
    // see we should see the byte data of the image now.
    printf( "%d\n", bytes[ i ] );
  }
}
```

I found code from this site: http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/how-to-load-a-png-image-in-c/

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=20166), 1290 means the image path wasn't found. Try using an absolute file path and see if it can load then.